# How to solve Identifer Expected problem in C# unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is my code in which the identifier problem causes.

```
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
{
    Text[] = buttons[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();
}
```

Comment: you have not given your variable a name. Try Text[] texts = buttons[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();

Comment: The question should probably contain a bit more details, at least the exact message and location of the error that you're getting (e.g. `(3,12): error CS1001: Identifier expected`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unknown identifier:** This type of error could mean that Unity does not know the variable that you are referring to and it is expecting an Identifier.
This might be due to these reasons:

- The name of the variable that you are using is incorrect.
- The variable has not been declared yet.
- The variable has been declared but outside the scope of the method.

Note: The names of all variables and functions are case-sensitive, just using an incorrect case, will assume that you're referring to another variable.

Try this:

```
   for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Length; i++)
   {
       Text[] texts = buttons[i].GetComponentsInChildren<Text>();
   }
```

You can refer these links [link-1](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1376530/add-listeners-to-array-of-buttons.html) [link-2](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1004722/how-to-get-an-array-of-all-buttons-attached-to-a-p.html)